# Android SAX XML Parser with String or Stringbuilder or Stringbuffer

Tags: android, string, saxparser

I have an xml that i am parsing there is a field that contains very long text, but somehow it is dropped by the parser, is it so because i am using just string to get those character to should i use string buffer or builder. What i want is to extract value by tag only.

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

    if (elementOn) {
     // its not reading element value, though tag is read.
        elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        elementOn = false;
    }
}
```

This is the text:

```
  <description>
   <![CDATA[
  Former CPI MLA Manish Kunjam, who returned on Thursday after, theis is a long long text very long that its being dropped.......so what can be done...................................................................................................
  ]]>
 </description>
```

Thanks plz guide me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a StringBuilder since text can be read in chunks and you may be reading just the first empty line of code like this. See [documentation](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)

You can reset the StringBuilder each time you hit `startElement`

```
private final StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
private String elementValue = null;
private boolean elementOn = false;

public final void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
     if (elementOn)
         mStringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
}

public final void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {
    mStringBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (someCondition) elementOn = true;
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
     elementValue = mStringBuilder.toString().trim();
     elementOn = false;
}
```

Parser does about the following

```
  <description> -> startElement("description"), reset StringBuilder
   <![CDATA[    -> characters(""), appended to (empty) String 
  Former CPI..  -> characters("Former.."), appended 
  ]]>           -> characters(""), appended
 </description> -> endElement("description"), read text here
 <description> -> startElement("description"), reset StringBuilder all starts again
```

Comment: Yes, but this will give me a long string containing all tags.....is there any way i can get only individual tags only...

Comment: it should give you only the content of one element since it resets the StringBuilder each time a new element starts.